# Are the existance of buddhist dieties a problem for hinduism?

Tags: gods

I have asked many times to different people on different websites what the buddhas,bodhisattvas and dakinis are.what I mean by that,is that buddhas,bodhisattvas and dakinis exist because they come to people in pure visions(even bestowing upon them siddhis),they possibly incarnate,they bring people to their purelands in many pureland accounts(there are hundreds of them),and appear to delogs in NDEs.so they do exist.Jayaratha the kashmir shaivite siddha taught them to be false gods.so he did think they existed,just that they were deceptive.

but the answer I always get from some people(Usually kevaladvaitins)is that these are buddhist yogis that have attained enlightenment.but you ask how can this be possible if:

1.they reject any supreme creator existing like Ishvara and believe the devas have no causal power over maintenance,creation ,destruction or prayala.

2.they believe the Vedas are folly(as the pali suittas say)or created by Manjusri as an upaya(per the manjusrimakalpa)

3.they believe in anatman(the belief that no permanent self exists and that there is nos elf beyond the 5 aggregates)

and they even reject Advaita.and buddhist enlightenment has no Vedana(Feeling)of Bliss or any Vedana.mahayanists even believe that they have no Vijnana.So its not the same thing even without them rejecting ishvara,vedas,devas as superior and the atman.

So I don't know why some people always like to claim buddhist enlightenment is the same as hindu enlightenment.

the Existance of Buddhas,boddhisattva,dakinis IS likely a problem for hinduism because here we have a bunch of beings that follow the same philosophy from different universes and exisiting within their own realms(Purelands).unless Jayaratha is right that these are false gods(what would that be deceptive spirits?Asuras?Nature spirits?)then hinduism has a problem with these beings merely existing because it possibly proves buddhism is true.otherwise why would these beings even exist.we even have modern day people becoming buddhas and reaching the rainbow body as outlined in Buddhist tantra.

so why is their existance not a problem for hindu Dharma's Validity?

Comment: “Jayaratha the kashmir shaivite siddha taught them to be false gods.so he did think they existed,just that they were deceptive.” can you write the source of this statement?